# How to scrape these player ratings from Squawka

Tags: web-scraping

I want to scrape the player ratings from Squawka, if I just do a URL request and parse the content in Python using BeautifulSoup, I do not see the ratings or player names show up anywhere. How should I proceed? For the specific URL see:

http://www2.squawka.com/football-player-rankings#performance-score#player-stats#english-premier-league|season-2017/2018#all-teams#all-player-positions#16#40#0#0#90#11/08/2017#13/05/2018#season#1#all-matches#total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not embedded in the html but is retrieved from another JSON api http://www2.squawka.com/wp-content/themes/squawka_web/leaderboard_process-v2.php with some url parameters :

http://www2.squawka.com/wp-content/themes/squawka_web/leaderboard_process-v2.php?type=Player%20Stats&filter=2&league=819&team=0,31,299,301,302,33,169,34,309,315,36,37,38,39,43,44,46,47,323,48,49&played=All%20matches&position=All%20Player%20Positions&agestart=16&ageend=40&noofmatch=0&seasonstart=11/08/2017&seasonend=13/05/2018&by=season&timestart=0&timeend=90&is_home=1&showtype=total

To get the player full name and the total, using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```bash
curl -s 'http://www2.squawka.com/wp-content/themes/squawka_web/leaderboard_process-v2.php?type=Player%20Stats&filter=2&league=819&team=0,31,299,301,302,33,169,34,309,315,36,37,38,39,43,44,46,47,323,48,49&played=All%20matches&position=All%20Player%20Positions&agestart=16&ageend=40&noofmatch=0&seasonstart=11/08/2017&seasonend=13/05/2018&by=season&timestart=0&timeend=90&is_home=1&showtype=total' | \
     jq  '[ 
            .result | .. | {total: .data?.total?, name: .info?.full_name?} | select(.total != null) 
          ] | sort_by(.total) | reverse'
```

Comment: I was wondering how I ---as a very inexperienced webscraper --- could have figured this out myself, what are the steps you took to figure this out?

Comment: open development console on your browser, go to network tabs, refresh the page. look at the html body of the main page, if your data isn't there it's probably in additionnal request, look for iframe in this case, if there arn't any it's an API call from JS. further look at the requests in the network tabs until you find the one that has the data